# gdb Breakpoint on assert on in multithreaded C program

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I'm using `assert` from `<cassert>` to check invariants in my multithreaded C++11 program. When the assertion fails, I'd like to be able to inspect the state of the failing function, along with still-intact backtrace, variable state, etc. at the time of the failed assertion. The issue seems be some interaction between `SIGABRT` and my threads, as my `std::thread`s are `pthread_kill`ed, presumably by some default signal handler. How can I pause gdb right at the time of the failed assertion?

Here are some things I've tried:

1. set a catchpoint on `SIGABRT`. This catch does occur, but it's too late (in `__pthread_kill`).
2. defined `__assert_fail`, which is `extern` declared in `<assert.h>`, and set a gdb breakpoint on it. This is never caught so presumably the pthread is being killed before this is called (?).

What's the recommended approach here?

Comment: @Klaus thank you for your answer and thanks for following up. This turns out to be a red herring and actually the real answer is that no special configuration of gdb is required at all. It turns out I had a different issue with my gdb setup that I thought was a  problem with not having the right breakpoints/catchpoints, but it was working all along. I'll post a clarifying response. You are correct about setting a breakpoint in the assert code if it was necessary to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a breakpoint on assert for some reason, Klaus's answer to break on `__assert_fail` is absolutely correct.

However, it turns out that setting a breakpoint to see stack traces in gdb on multithreaded programs is simply not necessary at all, as gdb already breaks on `SIGABRT` and switches the the aborting thread. In my case I had a misconfigured set of libraries that lead to this red herring. If you are trying to see stack traces from aborted code (`SIGABRT`) in gdb using multithreaded programs, you do not need to do anything in gdb, assuming the default signal handlers are in place.

FYI, you can see the default signal handlers by running `info signals`, and the same for just `SIGABRT` by running `info signals SIGABRT`. On my machine, I see this, which shows that the program will be stopped, etc. If for some reason your `SIGABRT` signal handler is not set up to stop on `SIGABRT`, you need to change that setting. More info at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html.

```
(gdb) info signals SIGABRT
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGABRT       Yes   Yes Yes     Aborted
```

Answer (score 4):

I did the following:

Example programm:

```
#include <cassert>
void f2()
{   
    assert(0);
}   

void f1()
{   
   f2();
}   

int main()
{   
    f1();
}
```

Now I set a breakpoint to f2 in hope I can step down to the assert with `stepi` later:

```
gdb > break f2
gdb > run
Breakpoint 11, f2 () at main.cpp:5
gdb > stepi // several times!!!!
0x080484b0 in __assert_fail@plt ()
```

Ahhh! As we can see `stepi` goes to symbol which tells us that there is a function with that name. So set simply a breakpoint for `__assert_fail@plt`

```
gdb > break __assert_fail@plt
gdb > run
Breakpoint 11, f2 () at main.cpp:5

(gdb) bt
#0  0x080484b0 in __assert_fail@plt () 
#1  0x080485f7 in f2 () at main.cpp:5
#2  0x08048602 in f1 () at main.cpp:10
#3  0x0804861b in main () at main.cpp:15
```

Works for me!